# Only last excel data is put in model

Tags: python, django, excel, sqlite

I wanna parse excel and put data in the model(User). However now,only last excel data is put in model and the number of the data is 4.4 is the number of all excel rows like
[image: excel]

Now db.sqlite3 is

```
|10|Karen|||
|10|Karen|||
|10|Karen|||
|10|Karen|||
```

My ideal db.sqlite3 is

```
1|1|Blear|40|false|l
2|5|Tom|23|true|o
3|9|Rose|52|false|m
|10|Karen|||
```

all data wanna be put in there.
Why does such result happen?
views.py is

```
#coding:utf-8
from django.shortcuts import render
import xlrd
from .models import User

book = xlrd.open_workbook('../data/data.xlsx')
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(1)

for row_index in range(sheet.nrows):
  rows = sheet.row_values(row_index)  
  print(rows) 

def build_employee(employee):
  if employee == 'leader':
     return 'l'
  if employee == 'manager':
     return 'm'
  if employee == 'others':
     return 'o'

for row in rows:
  is_man = rows[4] != ""
  emp = build_employee(rows[5])
  user = User(user_id=rows[1], name_id=rows[2], name=rows[3], 
              age=rows[4],man=is_man,employee=emp)
  user.save()
```

When i print out rows in `print(rows)` ,result is

```
Blear
Tom
Rose
Karen
```

so I think rows has all data in excel.
models.py is

```
class User(models.Model):
    user_id = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    name_id = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    man = models.BooleanField()
    TYPE_CHOICES = (
    ('m', 'manager'),
    ('l', 'leader'),
    ('o', 'others'),
     )
    employee =models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: Just want to check that you are accessing sheet 2 by calling  `sheet = book.sheet_by_index(1)` , if you want to access sheet 1 you need to call `sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)`

Comment: @bulbus it is ok because I wanna read sheet 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of this block `rows` has only the values of last row(The row with`Karen`).

```
for row_index in range(sheet.nrows):
  rows = sheet.row_values(row_index)  
  print(rows)
```

Now after the above when you do the below you are iterating over values in the last row. Also remember you are not using `row` inside the for block which is a single cell value iterating over`['',10,'Karen','','','']`

```
for row in rows:
  is_man = rows[4] != ""
  emp = build_employee(rows[5])
  user = User(user_id=rows[1], name_id=rows[2], name=rows[3], 
              age=rows[4],man=is_man,employee=emp)
  user.save()
```

You should correct the above block as below..

```
for row_index in range(sheet.nrows):
  rows = sheet.row_values(row_index)  
  is_man = rows[4] != ""
  emp = build_employee(rows[5])
  user = User(user_id=rows[1], name_id=rows[2], name=rows[3], 
              age=rows[4],man=is_man,employee=emp)
  user.save()
```

Please note that I've not taken due care about the header row. Please do so at your end if need be.

Comment: Also there should be six identical entries in your db, I'm surprised there are only four!

Comment: thx,ur answer.I read ur answer,but I cannot understand where I should rewrite.I cannot find difference between my codes & yours.Where should I fix?And,why do  you think  there should be six identical entries ?Is it this User(user_id=rows[1], name_id=rows[2], name=rows[3], 
              age=rows[4],man=is_man,employee=emp) place? If u are i,how wil u write to avoid db number error?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion earlier, I just pasted your code and pointed where it was going wrong, I had not put in any corrected code. Now I've edited to put in the corrected code block. Please replace 'ONLY your last for loop with mine and see if it works.

Comment: thank u very much!!I could understand what is wrong.however,u already wrote but I did not care about the header row,so invalid literal for int()  error happens.If I skip header( i wanna skip 1st&2nd rows in excel),how should write it?How should I embet skipping header codes in your answer codes?

Comment: To skip one row try `range(1,sheet.nrows)`. If you want to skip two rows try `range(2,sheet.nrows)`. Both in place of `range(sheet.nrows)`

Comment: Also I did not point out earlier, as it was not relevant to the question, and am curious if User model would accept if `employee==None` as that is what should happen for the `Karen's` entry in the db.